# Fail in Test Laravel 8 (Problem with a route)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

--- There is my code of AddItemTest.php i want to do post to the route "products" function store ----

```
namespace Tests\Feature;
use App\Models\Employee;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use function PHPSTORM_META\map;
class AddItemTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    /** @test */
    public function an_employee_can_add_products()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $employee = Employee::factory()->create();

        $this->actingAs($employee);

        $this->post(
            'products.store',
            [
                'name' => "test",
                'product_type_id' => 1,
                'brand_id' => 1,
                'status' => 1,
                'quantity' => 100,
                'price' => 150,
                'image' => "test"
            ]
        );

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('products', [
            'name' => "test",
            'product_type_id' => 1,
            'brand_id' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
            'quantity' => 100,
            'price' => 150,
            'image' => "test"
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the error i catch is this. If you see the route is bad, i think here is the problem: POST https://localhost/http://localhost/products.store`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0IVo.png

This is the phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Use the path not the route name: `->post('/products', ...`

Comment: I added this, but i still having the same error

Comment: This is prefixed with `api`? If so try : `->post('/api/products', ...`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a route called `products.store` that probably maps to a `/products` endpoint or something similar.

In your test you are posting to the literal route `products.store` rather than `route('products.store')`. This is why you are seeing `http://localhost/products.store` in your test failure.

Assuming you have a route called `products.store`, update your test to this:

```
$this->post(
    route('products.store'),
    [
        'name' => "test",
        'product_type_id' => 1,
        'brand_id' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
        'quantity' => 100,
        'price' => 150,
        'image' => "test"
    ]
);
```

Comment: I try this, and i still having the same error, the route generated is this POST https://localhost/http://localhost/api/products

Comment: What is your `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: This is: APP_URL=https:http://localhost
I don't know why duplicate this route

Comment: Well for starters, that is an invalid URL, please update it to `https://localhost`. What does your `phpunit.xml` file look like?

Comment: I added to the question